# Why bluetoothAdapter callback is throwing error while connecting BLE device?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with `BluetoothAdapter` and trying to connect `BLE` device.
While I am trying to detect `BLE` device it throws following **error**.

```
2018-12-17 18:19:03.374 15642-15663/? E/ScanRecord: unable to parse scan record: [2, 1, 5, 17, 6, 67, 79, 77, 46, 72, 65, 78, 78, 65, 73, 78, 83, 84, 95, -80, -1, 2, -1, 0, 21, 9, 72, 73, 49, 48, 56, 51, 50, 32, 112, 72, 32, 49, 49, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 50, 32, 5, 18, -112, 0, -96, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2018-12-17 18:19:03.375 15642-15663/? E/BtGatt.JNI: An exception was thrown by callback 'btgattc_scan_result_cb'.
2018-12-17 18:19:03.376 15642-15663/? E/BtGatt.JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.util.SparseArray.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.bluetooth.le.ScanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData(ScanRecord.java:104)
        at android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter.matches(ScanFilter.java:317)
        at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.matchesFilters(GattService.java:883)
        at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.onScanResult(GattService.java:781)
```

I am running this app on pixel (android version 28) and nokia mobiles which are stock android devices. unable to find any solution.
I have asked for Location permission. Attaching some parts of my code to understand it better.

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:minSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
  <service
    android:name="com.lab.BluetoothLeService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:ignore="ExportedService">
   </service>
```

**calling for startLeScan**

```
 if(bluetoothAdapter!= null) {
            bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
```

**callback**

```
 private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
                printScanRecord(scanRecord);
                StringBuilder scanData = new StringBuilder(scanRecord.length);
                for (byte dataByte : scanRecord) {
                    scanData.append(String.format("%02X ", dataByte).trim());
                }

                String scanResult = scanData.toString().trim();

                Log.e("SCAN DATA", scanResult );

                });
```

But in non android one device I have not found null pointer exception.

Looking for solution which can connect to my BLE device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the advertised manufacturer data is invalid

`0xff 0x00`

Manufacturer data must be at least two bytes after 0xff. Those two bytes should identify the manufacturer.

Comment: Emil it gets connected in samsung and other non stock android devices

Comment: Well I guess the behaviour of detecting a device with invalid advertisement data should be undefined, so please fix the device so it advertises correct data. Anyway, the bug that the thread throws an exception was recently fixed in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4c2aa61202f906f52d3e5bd7f0910b0a4d837fae%5E%21/#F0.

Comment: Emil is it handled in android 28 or it will be next update

Comment: It was just fixed so it might take a while to get rolled out.

Comment: Emil one more thing in this case as you said scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData() is returning null. But what is pinching is that in samsung J7 device I am able to get result.getRssi() and other device information. But in pixel 1 device unable to fetch same BLE device. May I know why this is happening

Comment: Is not having Manufacturer data  only reason why **pixel or stock android devices** are unable to detect BLE device.

Comment: If you don't have manufacturer data, just remove the field completely from the advertising data (i.e. just remove 0xff 0x00). From the exception it seems like the advertising data parser crashed due to the incorrect data and therefore dropped the packet.