# Android "Error: unable to parse scan record" when using ScanSettings in Bluetooth LE Connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am really new to BLE. I am been having problem in Scanning a BLE device and using nRF it turned out that we need to apply some scan settings to see the device. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to apply scan settings without applying scan filters. The device seems to returning data in a non-standard way and android API doesn't call the callback function if it is unable to parse it. All I see is the error messages in logcat. The error message text matches [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b661bb7/core/java/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord.java) Line 261.

What I want to know is that how do I make sure that the callback is called when scansettings are applied. I know how to parse data by myself but so far I am having no success in getting my hand on the raw data.

Thanks.

P.S:
Some related questions:
[no callback when using ScanFilter in Bluetooth LE Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890042/no-callback-when-using-scanfilter-in-bluetooth-le-connection)
[BLE Scan Record Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417489/ble-scan-record-explanation)
[Why bluetoothAdapter callback is throwing error while connecting BLE device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844676/why-bluetoothadapter-callback-is-throwing-error-while-connecting-ble-device)

Comment: I did some other tests and I gave up on using filters and settings.
When I apply filters, the scan result is always empty.

Comment: Can confirm, ScanFilter can wreak havoc on the data in scan results.